# How to get value from new android material design Slider

Tags: android, material-design, android-seekbar, material-components-android, android-slider

Using new material design slider `com.google.android.material.slider.Slider`. The documentation is quite poor for it as it has been just recently released. Trying to get value from slider but no luck for now. In other words, what would be a slider's equivalent of `setOnProgressChanged { }` from Seekbar.

Comment: post your code please

Answer (score 18):

```
  Slider slider = findViewById(R.id.slider);
  slider.addOnSliderTouchListener(touchListener);
```

Then

```
private final OnSliderTouchListener touchListener =
      new OnSliderTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(Slider slider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(Slider slider) {

        }
      };
```

For more details, Check [**`SliderMainDemoFragment.java`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/catalog/java/io/material/catalog/slider/SliderMainDemoFragment.java)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The OnChangeListener reports every single change, even when still dragging. OnSliderTouchListener reports only once, after the slider touch is released.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. And the value would be retrieved in onStopTrackingTouch by calling slider.getValue().

Answer (score 16):

You can use the `OnChangeListener` listener

```
slider.addOnChangeListener(new Slider.OnChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(@NonNull Slider slider, float value, boolean fromUser) {
        //Use the value
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

To get value updates you can use `Slider.OnChangeListener`:

```
val slider = Slider(requireContext())
slider.addOnChangeListener { slider, value, fromUser -> /* `value` is the argument you need */ }
// the same implementation with interface name
// slider.addOnChangeListener(Slider.OnChangeListener { slider, value, fromUser -> })
```

Examples of slider implementation from [Material Components official repository](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/tree/master/catalog/java/io/material/catalog/slider/).

Answer (score 1):

We can get the **value** of the slider using **addOnChangeListener**.

> The parameter **value** is of type Float.

```
    slider.addOnChangeListener { slider, value, fromUser ->                            
              Toast.makeText(baseContext, value.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right you are trying to get the value of the `Slider` on the go.

As far as I can see there is no direct method for that, but we can utilize a `Labelformatter` to do so.

A `Labelformatter` gets the value of the `Slider`, modifies it and returns it so that it can be displayed in the label above the `Slider`. In there you can add you lines of code processing the value.

Create a `Labelformatter`:

```
formatter = new LabelFormatter() {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
            //do what you want with the value in here...
            return "" + value;
        }
    };
```

Afterwards just add the `Labelformatter` to your `Slider` with

```
slider.setLabelFormatter(formatter);
```

<strike>**Caution:** This only works when you choose to show the label on the `Slider`</strike>

**Edit:**

If you don't want the label to show up, you will have to create your own style for the label making it invisible.

Create a style in `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="LabelStyle" parent="ShapeAppearance.Material3.Tooltip"> //parent might be different for you
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Finally, add the style to the label in the xml of your layout

```
<com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
...                                
app:labelStyle="@style/LabelStyle"/>
```